Get the number of months in a year for non-gregorian calendar
I would like to get the number of months in a year for non-gregorian calendars.
For example, in the Hebrew calendar, year 5784 has 13 months, but year 5783 has 12 months.
I tried:
public extension Calendar {
    
    /// The range of months for a given year in the calendar
    func monthRange(year: Int) -> Range<Int> {
        let components  = DateComponents(calendar:  self,
                                         year:      year,
                                         month:     1,  //  I assume 1 is always valid
                                         day:       1)  //  I assume 1 is always valid
        let date        = self.date(from: components)!
        let monthRange  = self.range(of: .month, in: .year, for: date)!
        return monthRange
    }
}

with no luck (result is always 1..<14).
Note that:
public extension Calendar {

    func dayRange(year: Int, month: Int) -> Range<Int> {
        let components  = DateComponents(calendar:  self,
                                         year:      year,
                                         month:     month,
                                         day:       1)  //  I assume 1 is always valid
        let date        = self.date(from: components)!
        let dayRange    = self.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date)!
        return dayRange
    }
}

Is working fine (at least for Gregorian calendar, it gives indeed 29 days for leap-year February, 28 otherwise, and 30/31 days for other months). It also works correctly for Chinese calendar (30 or 31 days).

This is because of the meaning of the month component in the Hebrew calendar. A month value of 13 means Elul, and 1 means Tishri. The months Elul and Tishri are in every year, so the range is always 1..<14.
The difference between leap and non-leap years is whether the month represented by the value 6 exists or not. 6 means Adar I, and 7 is Adar or Adar II depending on whether it is a leap year.
If you just want to find out whether it is a year with a leap month, just check the number of days in a year.
let components = DateComponents(calendar: self, year: year)
guard let date = components.date,
      let rangeOfDays = range(of: .day, in: .year, for: date) else {
    // something went wrong...
}
if rangeOfDays.upperBound > 380 {
    // leap year!
}


Thanks. Not exactly the answer to my question, as I really want the number of months, but that put me on the way. This means that there can be holes in the month numbering (e.g. non-leap years don't have month 7). So the trick is to ask the calendar the time interval since reference date for 1/6/yyyy and the time interval since reference date for 1/7/yyyy. For 5784 the values are different (and the month names with DateFormater are indeed Adar I and Adar II). For 5783 the values are the same (and the month names with DateFormater are also the same "Adar"). Seems to work for all calendars.

@AirXygène Once you know whether it is a leap year, you would know the number of months, wouldn't you? :)

@AirXygène For this to work with all calendars, one way would be to find the range of months first, and for each month in the range, find the intervals since reference date.  Then the number of months would be the number of unique values you get from this.

Absolutely (to both your comments ).
I will post a code doing this before tomorrow.

Thanks to @Sweeper information, this does the job for any calendar. It only assumes that there is always a day number 1 in a month, which is, I think, a fair assumption:
public extension Calendar {
    
    /// Returns the list of months for a year
    ///
    /// It includes the month name (in the current locale) and the month number (to use in `DateComponents`)
    func monthsOf(year: Int) -> [(name:     String,
                                  number:   Int,
                                  dayRange: Range<Int>)] {
        //  Build an empty list
        var months      = [(name: String, number:   Int, dayRange: Range<Int>)]()
        
        //  Create objects for later use - I do this because I hate creating objects in loops
        let timeZone    = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        let formatter   = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar          = self
            formatter.dateFormat    = "MMMM"
        
        //  Create a Date DateComponents with the year only, and get the month range for that DateComponents
        let components  = DateComponents(calendar:  self,
                                        year:       year)
        if let date     = self.date(from: components) {
            if let monthRange = self.range(of: .month, in: .year, for: date) {
                
                //  Go through the range of months, and ask for the date (and time interval to reference) for each
                //  month. Compare it to the previous one. If it is the same, it indicates that in fact, this month
                //  does not exist. Otherwise, add it in the list.
                
                var referenceTimeInterval:  TimeInterval    =   0.0
                
                for monthIndex in monthRange {
                    //  I use UTC time, and 1st day of the month at 12:00:00 so to be sure that I have the same day
                    //  all around the world - maybe not needed, but I had to choose something.
                    let monthComponents             = DateComponents(calendar:  self,
                                                                     timeZone:  timeZone,
                                                                     year:      year,
                                                                     month:     monthIndex,
                                                                     day:        1,
                                                                     hour:      12,
                                                                     minute:     0,
                                                                     second:     0)
                    if let firstMonthDayDate        = self.date(from: monthComponents) {
                        let firstMonthDayInterval   = firstMonthDayDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
                        if firstMonthDayInterval != referenceTimeInterval {
                            //  This is a real new month !!!
                            //  Add it to the list
                            months.append((name:        formatter.string(from: firstMonthDayDate),
                                           number:      monthIndex,
                                           dayRange:    self.dayRange(year: year, month: monthIndex)))
                            referenceTimeInterval   = firstMonthDayInterval
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return months
    }
}

